# Cloud server read write access for network drives

Tags: cloud, nfs, drive

When creating new folders on a network drive anyone other than admins or the owner is unable to edit or add folders / files. Is there a way to map it using the same group policy that is mapping the drives?

I tried changing the NFS attributes but it didn't seem to change anything for the other users who needed access